# Add schema to Schema Registry with a specific Id

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

We have been using Confluent Schema Registry with KafkaStreams for over a year now and everything has been working well; until yesterday.

In an UAT environment we seem to have had a Schema subject deleted and one of our applications started failing over with the message

> [ERROR] LogAndFailExceptionHandler - Exception caught during
>   Deserialization, taskId: 0_13, topic: TOPIC_NAME, partition: 13,
>   offset: 0 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
>   retrieving Avro schema for id 1531

I checked the Schema Registry and noticed the subject was missing and queries the id 1531 that is listed in the error with curl such as:

```
curl -X GET http://SchemaRegistryHost:8081/schemas/ids/1531
```

And got back:

```
{"error_code":40403,"message":"Schema not found"}
```

I naively just tried to register the schema again without thinking about it and it worked but the id the schema was registered with was not the same as the previous 1531 ID.

I need the schema registered to the ID 1531 since the existing messages in the topic already contain that Id 1531 in the magic byte.

I checked the API docs at https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/develop/api.html but did not see anything for setting a given Id for a schema.

Is there anyway to force a schema to a specific Id with schema registry?

I am aware of some backup solutions but I am looking for a fix now that will hopefully prevent loss of data or extraordinary measures to fix the topic data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway to force a schema to a specific Id with schema registry?

There is not.

---

The ID of 1531 isn't actually "gone", by the way, it just is *marked* as deleted in the registry (consume the `_schemas` topic to see it).

---

There really is no way around the error that I know of while you use the KafkaAvroDeserializer. You would have to use the ByteArrayDeserializer, then "fix" or "lookup" the correct ID using the Schema Registry client, and then deserialize the rest of the message.

The other option would be to reset your consumer group such that you skip these messages entirely, or setup exception handling. [Handling bad messages using Kafka's Streams API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666756/handling-bad-messages-using-kafkas-streams-api)

Comment: The good news is that this is only a UAT environment so if we "skip" data it isn't the end of the world but it seems like had this happened in a production environment where there is actual financial cost with skipping messages this would not be an acceptable solution. 
Also seems getting production schema registry backed up and instituting better controls over deleting schema subjects may be very critical... though it seems like confluent should consider extending the API allow for such a use-case in these type of recovery situations.

Comment: there is no way to "unmark it as deleted" this seems a rather serious incident if there is no way to recover this. the more I read about this cases the more I'm reluctant to use confluent

Comment: @MiguelCosta Schema data is stored in Kafka, meaning it is append only, there is no "rollback". Deletes are therefore permanent.

Answer (score 5):

It s possible now !

doing this

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"schemaType": "AVRO", "version":1, "id":24, "schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"value_a1\",\"namespace\":\"com.mycorp.mynamespace\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"field1\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}" }' \
http://localhost:8081/subjects/my-cool-subject/versions
```

see : https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/installation/migrate.html#migrate-an-individual-schema-to-an-already-populated-sr