# Add schema to Apicurio Schema Registry with a specific Id

Tags: apache-kafka, apicurio-registry

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282944/add-schema-to-schema-registry-with-a-specific-id), we got into a sticky situation losing some schemas (but using the Apicurio Registry, not Confluent). We've managed to recover the schema and reregister them, but they got assigned new IDs.

Is there a way to upload a schema to a specific ID (the one we previously lost) in Apicurio?