# The kafka stream is not producing message to dlq topic from flat map values

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

```
valid.flatMapValues(v -> {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                List<JsonNode> result = Collections.singletonList(validmethods(v));
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                logger.info("Time taken to process :: " + (end - start));
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                SendToDeadLetterQueueExceptionHandler.sendtotopic(new ProducerRecord<String,String>(KafkaConstants.deadLetterTopic,e.getCause().toString()));
                logger.error("Exception in stream topology", e);
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.info("Time taken to process (errored out) :: " + (end - start));
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }).to(KafkaConstants.targetTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), producerserde()));
```

It shuts down the kafka stream incase of exception in validmethods(v).However if I stop producing to dlq topic from the catch block it works fine.

Comment: Maybe there is another error in `SendToDeadLetterQueueExceptionHandler.sendtotopic`? Btw, `SendToDeadLetterQueueExceptionHandler.sendtotopic` is nothing Kafka Streams provides. Is this something you implemented yourself? Or is this provided by some framwork like Spring?

Comment: No this is I implemented .It extends implements DeserializationExceptionHandler and handles any exception at the time of deserialisation.I am using the same producer from stream topology to handle buisness exceptions

Comment: Hard to say -- if it's your own code, I would suspect there might be a bug in your code...