# Skip record if Exception occurs in Topology

Tags: exception, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are writing a Kafka Streams Topology that aggregates data and displays them in real time. We would like to make the display as robust as possible - ideally log the record and continue for **any** exception.

According to the documentation, a few tests from us and

- [Handling exceptions in Kafka streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299528/handling-exceptions-in-kafka-streams)
- [Handling bad messages using Kafka's Streams API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666756/handling-bad-messages-using-kafkas-streams-api)
- https://groups.google.com/g/confluent-platform/c/p75CleJ9yU0

Kafka Streams very well supports handling exceptions that occur in the Producer or during Deserialization. The provided `LogAndContinueExceptionHandler` gives exactly our desired behavior. However our main problem are exceptions occuring during the processing (such as in `.mapValues()` or `.leftJoin()`

The ideas we had were basically to validate preconditions

1. During Deserialization and throw a DeserializationException (and log and continue) if they are not fulfilled.
2. As checks in the processing functions to return default values if a calculation cannot be performed (`/ by zero error`, etc.)

However if there is something unforeseen in the data an exception could still bubble up and the topology would shut down.

Kafka Streams provides an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` but it is called after the thread already died and therefore it cannot be used to prevent a topology shutdown.

Is there some way to write a UncaughtExceptionHandler that skips a record? Or alteratively a mechanism to skip the current record that we could in a `try-catch` block inside the processing function?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution is to write your processing operations (e.g: Mapper, Filter, etc) in way that you never throw any exception. For doing that, you can used a wrapper object which can be either in Success of in Error (eg: the `Either` type in scala). After that, you can use the `branch()` method to get two streams: one for success records and one for the errors.

The below code shows the basic idea :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<Object, Result<Object>> stream = builder.stream("my-topic")
            .map((k, v) -> {
                try {
                    // unsafe operation, i.e that may throw an exception
                    return KeyValue.pair(k, new Success<>(v));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return KeyValue.pair(k, new Error<>(e));
                }
            });
        KStream<Object, Result<Object>>[] branch = stream.branch((k, v) -> !v.hasError(), (k, v) -> v.hasError());

        // Handle the success steam
        KStream<Object, Result<Object>> successStream = branch[0];

        // Handle the error steam, e.g:  log errors, write errors to a Dead Letter Queue
        KStream<Object, Result<Object>> errorStream = branch[1];
        
    }

    public interface Result<T> {
        T get() throws Exception;
        Exception exception();
        boolean hasError();
    }

    public static class Success<T> implements Result<T> {

        private final T value;

        public Success(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public T get() throws Exception {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public Exception exception() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasError() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static class Error<T> implements Result<T> {

        private final Exception error;

        public Error(Exception error) {  this.error = error; }

        @Override
        public T get() throws Exception{
            throw error;
        }

        @Override
        public Exception exception() {
            return error;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasError() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

---

In addition, for the Deserialization exceptions you have mentionned, the project [Azkarra Streams](https://www.azkarrastreams.io/) provides some convenient java classes that can help you (eg. SafeSerdes, DeadLetterTopicExceptionHandler): [GitHub](https://github.com/streamthoughts/azkarra-streams/tree/master/azkarra-commons/src/main/java/io/streamthoughts/azkarra/commons/error)